Is Open Transactions on topic?
It's not exactly a derived crypto-currency, but it's an enabler technology that seems to be getting more integrated with Bitcoin.
Are questions on OT on topic here?

I would say occasionally
Using an analogous situation, if this site was about HTTP and someone was asking questions about HTML then the question would be clearly off-topic. HTML has little to do with HTTP other than using it as an efficient transport mechanism.
What is making OT appear on-topic is that it currently sees Bitcoin as being the most efficient method for value transfer. This gives rise to useful questions about how Bitcoin can  better serve OT requirements (where appropriate) but care should be taken to avoid questions that are just about OT without a Bitcoin angle.
Drawing again from the HTTP/HTML analogy, a question about HTTP URI formation and it's use within HTML anchor tags would be relevant, but one about CSS styling would not.

I think that some basic questions about OT, even those that have nothing to do with Bitcoin, might still be on topic. People need to understand what it is, and how it works. http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/2772/how-does-open-transactions-solve-the-double-spend-problem

I'd agree with that - let this site serve as a gateway to deeper knowledge. But we cannot allow Bitcoin SE to become OT SE.

I'll agree with @GaryRowe so long as nobody actually makes an OT SE. I don't see any proposals on A51 for it so I think we're safe for now.
